# I am trying to pass an arraylist of objects between two activities,

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass an arraylist of objects between two activities,

```
ArrayList<Employee> list1 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

list1 is having data .i am sending liske this

```
i.putStringArrayListExtra("CMPNY", list1);
```

but it showin an error

> The method putStringArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList)

please any one help how to send the list from one activity to another activity

Comment: Create ArrayList as `ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(); `

Comment: Can you change the title of your question?

Comment: Employee is class.it has some data.i adding employee data to arraylist.i am trying to send arraylist from one activity to another activity.

Comment: try putParcelableArrayListExtra() instead and answer of @Hardik

Comment: Put the `List<Employee>` in a POJO, then put that POJO into http://www.parcelabler.com/ and put that POJO into the bundle with `putParcelableExtra`, make sure `Employee` is also Parcelable (by throwing it into the Parcelabler)

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely pass the ArrayList of objects but the condition is your Employee class should be either implements Serializable or Parcelable.

```
class Employee extends Parcelable
{
    // Your member data
    // Your getter setter methods
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    /**
    * Storing the Student data to Parcel object
    **/
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    }
}
```

Check this link for [Parcelable](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-parcelable-example-passing-data-between-activities/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick

```
Intent i = new Intent();
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
ArrayList<Employee> passData = new ArrayList<Employee>();
bundle.putSerializable("data", passData);
i.putExtras(bundle);
```

Then you can send the bundle with intent to another activity and get back the data there using below

```
ArrayList<Employee> dataReceived = new ArrayList<Employee>();
dataReceived = (ArrayList<Employee>)getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("data");
```

You can use [Parcelable](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-parcelable-example-passing-data-between-activities/) also.Sending POJO class like above is bit slower than Parcelable.But i have used it.It worked smooth for me.

Comment: while i am using like this...ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();   Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("DATA", list); but,in another activity i am writing like this ArrayList<Employee> list1 = new ArrayList<Employee>();  list1=(ArrayList<Employee>())bundle.getSerializable("data");  {but bundle.getSerializable("data") is not getting}.please help me what i do

Comment: Hi setu basak ,while i am using ArrayList<Employee> list1= new ArrayList<Employee>();
list1= (ArrayList<Employee>)getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("data");                                i am getting error here -->  ArrayList<Employee> list1=(ArrayList<Employee>)getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("DATA");

Comment: setu basak please see my post and reply.

Comment: what is the error?? show me logcat...and one thing i noticed in your code i.e you are setting name or companyname one at a time and adding it to the list.why??

Comment: Hi Setu basak , it's not showing any error . while i am adding details into the DetailsEmp activity .it should be added into ArrayListin DetailsEmp Activity . i am sending the ArrayList data from DetailsEmp Activity to MainActivity using Bundle .but,MainActivity getting  data Null.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Your Pojo, Model Class implement **Serializable interface**

```
import java.io.Serializable;


    public class BatchDropDownPojo  implements Serializable
    {
        private String batchName;

        public String getBatchName() {
           return batchName;
       }

       public void setBatchName(String batchName) {
        this.batchName = batchName;
       }
}
```

**Step 2**
         Intent i=new Intent(BatchWiseReportActivity.this,SearchViewActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("batchList",batchDropDownPojoArrayList);
                        startActivity(i);
**Step 3**

```
    ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mylist");

ArrayList<BatchDropDownPojo> batchDropDownPojoArrayList;
batchDropDownPojoArrayList = (ArrayList<BatchDropDownPojo>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("batchList");
```

Comment: Perfectly Fine Happy Coding